# Swift operators on arrays whose contents match specific protocols, "where" keyword usage

Tags: swift, generics, operators

I'm trying to make a Swift operator that applies to all `Array`s which contain only `Numeric` elements, it should look something like this:

```
prefix operator ∑
prefix func ∑ (array: Array<T>) -> T where T == Numeric {
    var sum: T = 0
    for item in array {
        sum += item
    }
    return sum
}
```

but that's a compiler error (`error: 'where' clause cannot be attached to a non-generic declaration`)

I could, of course, write many functions in the form:

```
prefix operator ∑
prefix func ∑ (array: Array<Double>) -> Double {
    var sum: Double = 0
    for item in array {
        sum += item
    }
    return sum
}
```

which works, but the point of generics is that I shouldn't have to.

This is probably because I don't understand how to use the "where" keyword, but I'm finding it difficult to search for such a (no pun intended) generic word, as I get too many irrelevant results.

Edit:

And I can't write `prefix func ∑ (array: Array<Numeric>) -> Numeric {` because then Swift can't figure out how to compile `sum += item`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
prefix operator ∑
prefix func ∑ <T>(array: Array<T>) -> T where T: Numeric {
    var sum: T = 0
    for item in array {
        sum += item
    }
    return sum
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could *constraint* the generic type to be a [Numeric](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/numeric) by typing `<T: Numeric>`, thus the signature of the function would be:

```
func ∑ <T: Numeric>(array: Array<T>) -> T
```

I would also suggest to use [`reduce(_:_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2298686-reduce) method to achieve such a task:

```
prefix operator ∑
prefix func ∑ <T: Numeric>(array: Array<T>) -> T {
    return array.reduce(0, +)
}

// calling:
let array = Array(repeating: 1, count: 20)
let summation = ∑array // 20
```

For more information about generics type constraints, you could review [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH26-ID186).